# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getByText' of undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, unit-testing, jestjs, jsx

I am currently trying to work on a code that test's the fetching of an API of a component in React Native

This is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import { LoseView } from '../../../components';
import {render, screen, act} from "@testing-library/react-native"



describe('tests of the Lose View', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        global.fetch = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({
            json: () => Promise.resolve ({
                joke: "The Joke"
            })
        }))
    });

    it("Loads the joke on mount", async () =>{
        await act(async () => renderer.create(<LoseView />));
        expect(screen.getByText("The Joke")).toBeInDocument();
    })
}
```

This is the LoseView component that I'm trying to test:

```
const LoseView = () => {

const [currentJoke, setCurrentJoke] = useState("");

const fetchJokeApi = async () => {
    // Fetching data from the API
        await fetch("https://v2.jokeapi.dev/joke/Miscellaneous,Pun?blacklistFlags=nsfw,religious,political,racist,sexist,explicit&type=single")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => 
            setCurrentJoke(data.joke),
            );
  };

useEffect(() => {
    fetchJokeApi();
 }, [])

return(
    <View style={{ flex: 1,alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <Text>you lost!, have a lame consolation joke</Text>
        <Text>{currentJoke}</Text>
   </View>
);
}


export {LoseView};
```

The problem relies on the fact that the test doesn't pass because the "getByText" in the expect part of the test, sends out this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getByText' of undefined
```

What is wrong with my code? Is it the way I structured the text.

Comment: What is the version of @testing-library/react-native you're using?

Comment: @chengsam I am using the "^7.2.0",

Comment: I don't see there is `screen` exported from the library

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68569156/typeerror-cannot-read-property-getbytext-of-undefined#comment121194076_68569156), you're on version ^7.2.0 of [`@testing-library/react-native`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@testing-library/react-native). Upgrading to [10.1.0](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-testing-library/releases/tag/v10.1.0) or higher should allow you to import `screen` as you're doing.

I haven't verified your test beyond the import.